# Interfaces y sus métodos privados/protegidos en la clase que los implementa. ¿Es posible? C#

Tags: c#, interface

Esta es la primera interfaz que hago. La he hecho para obligar a las clases que la implementan a llevar cierta estructura/orden. Pero al hacelo me he dado cuenta de ciertas cosas.

Esta es la interfaz:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------
// La interfaz me obliga a que las referencias a los métodos sean públicos
// Esto a lo mejor tiene cierto sentido ya que ese metodo tiene que ser implementado
// por otra clase
//--------------------------------------------------------
public interface IBehaviour
{
    public void DoSomething();
}
```

Esta es la clase que la implementa:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------
// La interfaz me obliga a que las implementaciones de los métodos sean publicos
//--------------------------------------------------------
public class MyClass, IBehaviour
{
     public void DoSomething()
     {
          //code
     }
}
```

Esto último es lo que no me cuadra... o tal vez lo estoy haciendo mal?

¿Porque debería ser público el método "DoSomething()" si yo sé que no va a ser usado en ningún otro lugar?

Es posible hacer que sea privado?

O tal vez no estoy comprendiendo bien el verdadero proposito y finalidad de las interfaces?

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Cual seria el problema que sea public si no lo heredas no lo podes usar, Despues cuando vos heredas de una Interface a dos clases, podes usar polimorfimos, entonces tu Objeto es `IBehavior MyIBehavior`.

Comment: Gracias Ramiro!! Y si quisira que ninguna clase derivada de MyClass heredara ese método se podría hacer de alguna forma?

Comment: hasta lo que yo se o recuerdo no se puede. Porque te da error al querer colocar un metodo private o protected.

Comment: Muchas Gracias Ramiro!!